# Alterando valor de objeto inserido em uma array

Tags: javascript, array

Dê uma olhada neste exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/b4w6jqgf/1/

Nele tenho duas arrays:

```
__options e __defaultOptions;
```

Ao iniciar dou push em __options inserindo o objeto __defaultOptions.
Posteriormente efetuo a alteração do valor do objeto na posição 0, setando no campo "maxsize" o valor 1500.

Acontece que o valor é atribuído também em todas as outras posições da array.

Imagino que esteja apenas referenciando o objeto __defaultOptions nas posições do array, sendo o mesmo objeto em todas as posições, assim quando efetuo a alteração do valor em uma das posições, todos tem seu valor alterado.

Como posso contornar esta questão?

Há algum meio de importar os dados de um objeto em si, e não referenciar o objeto?

Answer (score 0):

Bastou utilizar **JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())** para criar uma cópia do objeto.

Demo da correção: https://jsfiddle.net/b4w6jqgf/2/